Missing flyway postgres jar in classloader on fly.io deploy
I'm trying to deploy a Ktor application with Flyway migration on startup. I've had no issues up until now, but when I added the migration step on startup, it fails because the flyway-database-postgresql dependency (And the relevant class PostgreSQLDatabaseType.class) is not being loaded by the default class loader.
When I SSH into the VM and check the actual contents of the deployed fat jar, I find the file there, so it's not a missing file or a maven issue (as far as I know). The maven entry looks pretty standard:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-database-postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>10.17.3</version>
    </dependency>

When I log the defined packages in my application main function, I get a long list, including some flyway packages, but not the one I need. I use the following code to print all the loaded packages:
Application::class.java.classLoader.definedPackages.flatMap { it.name.split(":") }.forEach { println("Found package from class loader: $it") } I've also tried with ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().
Everything works when I boot it up on my own machine, and the list of defined packages include the relevant package (org.flywaydb.database.postgresql), which it does not do on the fly machine.
In the Manifest.mf file, I find the following package on the class path: flyway-database-postgresql-10.17.3.jar. Is it Kotlin related? Something to do with the ClassLoader? I build with a Dockerfile, but it's pretty standard, and since the correct files end up in the jar, I doubt that's the issue.
Does anyone have any idea what might be the issue? It seems like a class path issue somewhere, but I have no idea how to sort out something like this, unfortunately.
My code (shrunk down dramatically): https://github.com/evengul/mc-org/tree/reproduce-error/webapp. It still works locally, but you can take a look at it if you want.
